# Break dependency on template argument

Tags: c++, templates

In a project, I convert a run-time dimensioned Mesh object to a compile-time  one. For that, I convert the class into a template.

I have a template Mesh and shared pointer to it:

```
template<int dim> class Mesh; 

template<int dim> using PtrMesh = std::shared_ptr<Mesh<dim>>;
```

PtrMesh is used frequently throughout the entire project. That is not a problem as long as its just a function argument:

```
template<int dim> void fun(PtrMesh<dim> mesh);
```

dim is deduced from the caller here.

But when the PtrMesh is a type of a member variable or a methods return type:

```
template<int dim> 
class X { 
  PtrMesh<dim> mesh; 
};
```

This class has always to be converted to a template and dim must be known when the class is instantiated. That way, the change creeps much farer than I anticipated.

Are there possibilities to break this dependency or work around it?

One way, I think, is to use boost::any, but this is also not transparent to the user of PtrMesh.
Assignments like *PtrMesh mesh = getMesh()* can be rewritten as *auto mesh = getMesh*

C++ 11 is the standard.

Best Thanks!

Comment: That's kind of the consequence of using a compile-time dimension. You either need it (and hence, propagate it everywhere) or you don't.

Comment: You can use a view if applicable. In my case, I have a buffer that express his format in template parameter. I have also a `BufferObjectView`, which don't allow editing, but is not templated.

Comment: If my Mesh has methods that have a dependent type (a type that uses dim) as return value, I can't declare them in the Base class. Thus I still need to cast the PtrBase to a PtrMesh<dim> before I can use such functions and thus know dim at compile time. If I am wrong, could you provide an example?

Comment: I don't really understand what you ask for?